# UriBuilder escapes the ? to %3F, but not in every application

Tags: c#, .net, url

I am using the UriBuilder to create a Uri including a query.
I want to create a Uri like this:

```
file:///C:/ProgramData/bla/index.html?cs=6000
```

but what I get is this:

```
file:///C:/ProgramData/bla/index.html%3Fcs=6000
```

my code looks like this:

```
const string HELP_DIRECTORY_NAME = "help";
const int TOPIC_ID = 6000;

var baseUri = new Uri(@"C:\ProgramData\bla\");
var builder = new UriBuilder(baseUri);
builder.Path = $"{baseUri.AbsolutePath}{HELP_DIRECTORY_NAME}/index.html";

builder.Query = $"cs={TOPIC_ID}";

string absoluteUri = builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

and the absoluteUri is:

```
file:///C:/ProgramData/bla/help/index.html?cs=6000
```

But called from my VB.Net application it is:

```
file:///C:/ProgramData/bla/help/index.html%3Fcs=6000
```

using the same code.

No clue if VB.Net plays a role here, my understanding is it shouldn't.

How can I stop the UriBuilder from escaping my query?

Comment: You code C# works as expected. So I guess this is a VB problem. Maybe you should add the vb tag to your question.

Comment: Can you show your VB code?

Comment: The VB.Net code is simply calling this code from a C# dll. It's just the only thing that's differently. C# apps calling the code are working

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by rendering?

Comment: My guess is that VB.Net has nothing to do with it. question remains, why does it work in one application, not in the other?

Comment: it fails only in file:/// Uris, not in http:// Uris
how is that different?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, i am treating web addresses and file names the same way.
is there something I have to do to create a file:/// Uri with a query?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the VB code does nothing. The Uri is escaped when I call the function above from that VB application. If it is related to VB.Net - I don'.t know! When I call it from other applications - no problem. The VB-Net app is simply calling this code from a dll.

Comment: @HankTheTank post the *actual* code and mention the runtime you are using. Runtime functions don't change behaviour from one language to the next. There *was* a change in how URIs are escaped in .NET 4.5, to fix some incompatibility issues. Given that the earliest supported runtime is 4.5.2, it's quite likely that you are running one of the two snippets on an older, unsupported runtime.

Comment: @HankTheTank btw don't edit the question to bump it - it will only attract more close and down votes. It's not a good question as it is, as it doesn't contain the *actual* code and omits critical information - the runtime version used. It's not possible to test the code you posted to reproduce the problem

Comment: @HankTheTank btw it's not even UriBuilder that's escaping anything. It's the Uri class itself. `builder.Uri` returns a `Uri` instance. You are calling `Uri.AbsoluteUri` on it to convert it to a *string* - the very thing that [changed in .NET 4.5](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/10/beware-of-uri-tostring/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that' was the problem. we switched to 4.7.2, but we forgot to update this one project. it was still on Framework 4. Now the behaviour is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @PanagiotisKanavos has pointed out, the behavior of the Uri class changed somewhere in the Framework version 4.5.
We were migrating to 4.7.2, but we forgot to switch that one project.
With 4.7.2 it works as expected. this has nothing to do with VB.Net